# C# Winform refresh image cause delay

Tags: c#, winforms

I'm working on a [ECG](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Electrocardiography) project which show the ECG graph in real-time. I drawn my image in a Picturebox. And the way I used to update the image is using the Forms.Timer to call Invalidate() to refresh and update the image in picturebox  In the picturebox_paintmethod, I create a new Bitmap and using graphics to draw the new line and grid of the ECG every time.

So,now my problem is that I set the interval of the timer to 50ms or 100ms, but there is a delay which makes the image would not updating in the rate I want.

I know creating the new Bitmap will cause delay, but I didn't find a way to replace it. I was thinking I can draw the bitmap of the whole Ecg Data at the very beginning and move it to the left when the Timer tick, But I cannot find a way to just move the Bitmap in a Picturebox.

Does any one have any idea about this problem?

below is the code of my paint method.

```
private void pictureBox1_paint(object sender, PaintEventArgs e){
            // Draw the ECG.
            DrawArea = new Bitmap(pictureBox1.Size.Width,pictureBox1.Size.Height);
            using (g = Graphics.FromImage(DrawArea))
            {
                //dispose the original image.
                if (pictureBox1.Image != null)
                {
                    pictureBox1.Image.Dispose();
                }


                // draw the labels
                int numOfLabels = ((numOfCellsX - numOfCellsX % 4) / 4) * 2;

                for (int l = 0; l < numOfLabels; l++)
                {
                    g.DrawString((labelV).ToString(), drawFont, drawBrush, (unitOfLabel * l) + changeValueOfLabel, viewsizeY - 20);
                    labelV = labelV + unitOfLabel;
                }
                labelV -= numOfLabels * unitOfLabel;

                // draw horizontal lines of gird
                for (int y = 0; y <= numOfCellsY; ++y)
                {
                    g.DrawLine(bgp, 0, y * cellSizeY, viewsizeX, y * cellSizeY);
                }

                // draw vertical lines of gri， +6 because here we are drawing 6 more lines on the right of the grid for further moving.
                for (int x = 1; x <= numOfCellsX * 2; ++x)
                {
                    g.DrawLine(bgp, (x * cellSizeX) + changeValue, 0, (x * cellSizeX) + changeValue, viewsizeY);
                }

                //drawPoints
                g.DrawLines(mypen, points);

                //draw the most top line
                //g.DrawLine(bgp, viewsizeX - 1, 0, viewsizeX - 1, viewsizeY);
                // draw the most right line
                g.DrawLine(bgp, viewsizeX - 1, 0, viewsizeX - 1, viewsizeY);
                //draw the most left line
                g.DrawLine(bgp, 0, 0, 0, viewsizeY);
                // draw the bottom line, the reason that draw those line outside the for loop, is because the location.X of
                // the most left point of the picturebox is actually 599, therefore,it cannot display the 600 index point.
                g.DrawLine(bgp, 0, viewsizeY - 1, viewsizeX, viewsizeY - 1);

                // replace the image of the picturebox
                pictureBox1.Image = DrawArea;
            }
        }
```

The numberOfCellX and numberofLabel is under 15, numberOfCellYis under 8, And I've use the stopwatch to test the running time of the paint method which only took 2ms.

I also test the running time for whole iteration, including update the image and drawing it which took 27ms.So when I set the interval of Timer to 100ms. It will take around 127 ms to finish one Tick.

Updated Code without using Bitmap:

```
// Draw the ECG.
        g = e.Graphics;

            if (pictureBox1.Image != null)
            {
                pictureBox1.Image.Dispose();
            }


            // draw the labels
            int numOfLabels = ((numOfCellsX - numOfCellsX % 4) / 4) * 2;

            for (int l = 0; l < numOfLabels; l++)
            {
                g.DrawString((labelV).ToString(), drawFont, drawBrush, (unitOfLabel * l) + changeValueOfLabel, viewsizeY - 20);
                labelV = labelV + unitOfLabel;
            }

            labelV -= numOfLabels * unitOfLabel;


            // draw horizontal lines of gird
            for (int y = 0; y <= numOfCellsY; ++y)
            {
                g.DrawLine(bgp, 0, y * cellSizeY, viewsizeX, y * cellSizeY);
            }

            // draw vertical lines of gri， +6 because here we are drawing 6 more lines on the right of the grid for further moving.
            for (int x = 1; x <= numOfCellsX * 2; ++x)
            {
                g.DrawLine(bgp, (x * cellSizeX) + changeValue, 0, (x * cellSizeX) + changeValue, viewsizeY);
            }

            //drawPoints
            g.DrawLines(mypen, points);

            //draw the most top line
            //g.DrawLine(bgp, viewsizeX - 1, 0, viewsizeX - 1, viewsizeY);
            // draw the most right line
            g.DrawLine(bgp, viewsizeX - 1, 0, viewsizeX - 1, viewsizeY);
            //draw the most left line
            g.DrawLine(bgp, 0, 0, 0, viewsizeY);
            // draw the bottom line, the reason that draw those line outside the for loop, is because the location.X of
            // the most left point of the picturebox is actually 599, therefore,it cannot display the 600 index point.
            g.DrawLine(bgp, 0, viewsizeY - 1, viewsizeX, viewsizeY - 1);
```

Timer code:
     Update the coordinate of grid and points and call Invalidate to refresh the picturebox.

Comment: Hi, welcome to stack overflow. Please refer the
[ask] link for more details on how to ask a question and update your question accordingly. Add a minimal version of the code you have made for example.

Comment: Paint directly on the PictureBox surface (using the `PaintEventArgs`' `e.Graphics` object), you don't need a Bitmap here. You could move the drawing procedure to a self-contained method; pass the `e.Graphics` to this method. If/when you need to fix the drawing on a Bitmap, pass the Graphics object derived from a Bitmap. Btw, your code cannot be tested, too many parts missing.

Comment: Thank you for your advice, I removed the code about Bitmap and draw the lines on the PictureBox directly. However, the delay is still there. I can only reach 125 ms for the interval which is 8 frame per second at most without delay.

Comment: You haven't updated the code in the question with the modifications you applied, so it's not possible to see the problem (if there's one). If you updated it or post a new question to solve the problem, it'ld be useful to know the actual values of `numOfLabels`, `numOfCellsY`, `numOfCellsX` etc. The average number of iterations count a lot.

Comment: Sry, I just noticed that. now it's updated.

Answer (score 1):

DrawArea is an unmanaged ref type but you're not disposing it.

Under the hood of .net you're putting pressure on the GC. You could see this in CLR profiler that Gen2 is max'ing out. The GC is trying to free memory but the Dispose, Collection,  Resurrection and final malloc are taking longer than 50ms.

Put the DrawArea in a `using` or explicitly call  dispose on it at the end when you're finished working with it: `DrawArea.Dispose();`

Comment: I was thinking maybe it would be faster to directly draw onto a Panel, without bitmap and picturebox?

Comment: Thank you for your help! Actually every time when my Timer call the invalidate, I think I will create a new Bitmap and assign it to the DrawArea viariable. (I think that will dispose the old one), I'm new to Winform, please correct me if I was wrong.

Comment: Sure you could try that and perhaps compare that performance to the opposite by making the DrawArea a private member variable of the class.

Comment: I've tried to draw the lines directly on the Picturebox, but the delay is still there. The lowest interval I can set for my timer is 125 ms without any delay. And if I set the interval lower, the delay will increase by the time (For example, delay is 2 sec at the begining, but will increase to 10 at 1 mins later). Therefore, I was wondering there might be some mistake in somewhere else, but I have no idea where is it....

Comment: Why do you even have a Timer when the Paint event does the invalidating on its own? Also please [edit] your question to show the updated code and specify the number of labels and lines.

Comment: Hello, I was gonna use the Timer to call method that updating the image and  the invalidating for every 50ms(say i need 20fps).

Answer (score 0):

I found a kind dumb way to solve the problem. Say I have 240 points of data to draw in one second and if I set the interval of the timer to 50ms, I will need to draw 240/20 = 12 points to the picture for every Tick in order to draw 240 points in one second.

However, in this case I found that it need about 1.25 second to draw 240 points because of delay. Therefore, the dumb way I used is to draw 12*1.25 = 15 points for every tick of timer. Then I can draw 240 points in one second which would solve the problem.